# Accessing XML Node Value With Multiple Images

Tags: xml, html, xslt, web

My XML returned has multiple values of images, all in different sizes. I am trying to load in an image in my XSL but it always picks the smallest (first) image returned in XML so it is very pixelated.

How do I get the browser to pick the correct one, say depending on the size of the screen? Because the first one may as well be a .ico it is that small so on desktop is very pixelated.

Below is the code in the XML data and XSL file.

XSL:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="lfm/tracks/track">
         <xsl:sort  order="descending" data-type="number" select="playcount"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 8">
               <xsl:value-of select="result"/>

                       <div class="col s3 m3">
                             <div class="card large">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                   <img>
                                     <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
                                     </xsl:attribute>
                                   </img>

                                   <span class="card-title"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                   <p><xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                   </p>

                                   <p><xsl:value-of select="artist/name"/>
                                   </p>

                                   <p> Playcount: 
                                      <xsl:value-of select="playcount"/>
                                   </p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="card-action">
                                   <a href="view_song.html"><p>Link: 
                                      <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
                                   </p></a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>


             </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

XML:

```
 <track>
        <name>HUMBLE.</name>
        <duration>0</duration>
        <playcount>1063735</playcount>
        <listeners>136852</listeners>
        <mbid></mbid>
        <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar/_/HUMBLE.</url>
        <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
        <artist>
            <name>Kendrick Lamar</name>
            <mbid>381086ea-f511-4aba-bdf9-71c753dc5077</mbid>
            <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar</url>
        </artist>
        <image size="small">https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/a4a35fcdf62b8a532039012653eeea14.png</image>
        <image size="medium">https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/a4a35fcdf62b8a532039012653eeea14.png</image>
        <image size="large">https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/a4a35fcdf62b8a532039012653eeea14.png</image>
        <image size="extralarge">https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/a4a35fcdf62b8a532039012653eeea14.png</image>
 </track>
```

Comment: How are you using this xsl snippet? Like how is it run?

Comment: I found I could access different images if I subscripted like this image[4].

Comment: Putting in answer for better formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="image"/>
```

The xpath of `image` will access the first image element.

If you want to access the others you can use either a element index like `image[3]` or better you can base it on the size attribute, like the below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="image[@size = 'large']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by subscripting the image node with a number:
    `<xsl:value-of select="image[2]"/>`